# I cannot post my required data to my PHP website using my android app

Tags: php, android

Here is my code
My app crashes as soon as pressed send button

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
    public void send(View v)
    {

        //get message from message box
        String  msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();

        //check whether the msg empty or not
        if(msg.length()>0) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.soshelp.site50.net/index.php");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    msgTextField.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //display message if text field is empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All fields are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace from the LogCat?

Comment: you will need to run this in an asynctask

Comment: sir,can you help me more to implement asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put Your code in a separate thread in order to be correctly executed ,true for all server calls in android:

```
 public void send(View v)
    {

Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //get message from message box
        String  msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();

        //check whether the msg empty or not
        if(msg.length()>0) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.soshelp.site50.net/index.php");

            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "01"));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    msgTextField.setText(""); //reset the message text field
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            //display message if text field is empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All fields are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();

}
```

Comment: where exactly is the crash?

Comment: as soon as i press the button "send" it crashes